# How to mark _csrf cookie as secured for gitea?

Tags: csrf, csrf-protection, gitea

How to mark _csrf cookie as secured for gitea?

I was able to mark the ‘i_like_gitea’ cookie as secured by using the COOKIE_SECURE option,
but I am not able to mark the ‘_csrf’ cookie as secured

Answer (score 0):

I've not checked it yet

but it should be fixed by PR https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/pull/3833